# Is there any way to use pure Unicode to show a subscript lowercase c?

Tags: unicode

I am trying to hack around a UI issue where I can't easily use subscripts, and I was wondering if pure Unicode is a workaround. There are [superscripts and subscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) but they don't look like they include a "c" and I was wondering if there was some other way, like using [combining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/44330) [characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10414864/44330).

Comment: This sounds remarkably like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).  What kind of UI are you working on that requires a subscript lowercase c?

Comment: That sounds remarkably like an overeager citation of the XY problem.... In my case I need to have a label showing a mathematical symbol &omega;<sub>c</sub> (dammit, Markdown doesn't handle it either >:(  argh) that's $\omega_c$ for LaTeX fans