# How can I prevent unicode characters like this Ả̴̢̦̙̬̲̯̖̲̟̟̬̲̻̣̩͕͍̦͍̮̠̤͇̿́̾͋́̾̎̔̐̓̾̐̉͒̅͛̈́̀̇͋͋̔̕͘͝͝͝ on my site and why do they exist?

Tags: php, html, unicode

How to prevent characters like this one on my website:

```
Ả̴̢̦̙̬̲̯̖̲̟̟̬̲̻̣̩͕͍̦͍̮̠̤͇̿́̾͋́̾̎̔̐̓̾̐̉͒̅͛̈́̀̇͋͋̔̕͘͝͝͝
```

They are really annoying. Ḧ̶̡̡̢͙͚̝̖͙͓̝̘̯̜̗͙̩͎̻̥̩͈͈͈̘̰͇̞͇͇̦̼̺̙̲͔́̿͌̀̅͊̌́͂̋̃̽̔̀̇̎̈̆́̽̇͂͘͘͜͝͝A̸̡̧̲̦͕̦̦̘̫͍̺͙̫͉̠͆̈́̅̚ͅͅḦ̴̪̱̠̦̜̩͒̃͌̎̇͌̒̍̒̇̾̀͑̂̆̉̓͌͘̚̚̕͜͝ͅA̶̻͐̔̍̃͆̆̓̿͋͊̽͝

Comment: If you have them on your site, someone put them there. You need input sanitation if you allow someone to add content to your site

Comment: I don't have them on my site, I noticed them on another website. How to sanitize it?

Comment: This might also be worth looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414864/whats-up-with-these-unicode-combining-characters-and-how-can-we-filter-them

Comment: _How can I prevent unicode characters like this Ả̴̢̦̙̬̲̯̖̲̟̟̬̲̻̣̩͕͍̦͍̮̠̤͇̿́̾͋́̾̎̔̐̓̾̐̉͒̅͛̈́̀̇͋͋̔̕͘͝͝͝ on **my** site_

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the unicode characters outside of your desired [range(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

```php
$annoying_string = 'Ả̴̢̦̙̬̲̯̖̲̟̟̬̲̻̣̩͕͍̦͍̮̠̤͇̿́̾͋́̾̎̔̐̓̾̐̉͒̅͛̈́̀̇͋͋̔̕͘͝͝͝Ả̴̢̦̙̬̲̯̖̲̟̟̬̲̻̣̩͕͍̦͍̮̠̤͇̿́̾͋́̾̎̔̐̓̾̐̉͒̅͛̈́̀̇͋͋̔̕͘͝͝͝Ả̴̢̦̙̬̲̯̖̲̟̟̬̲̻̣̩͕͍̦͍̮̠̿́̾͋́̾̎̔̐̓̾̐̉͒̅͛̈́̀̇͋͋̔̕͘͝͝͝foobar̤͇';

$cleaned_string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $annoying_string);

echo $cleaned_string; // AAAfoobar
```