# Padding mixed CJK/ASCII input for monospaced output

Tags: unicode, fonts, unreal-engine4, cjk, monospace

I have been trying to solve this for some time. I have a need to output console stuff like:

```
          ABC-花海 | 123 | 456789
     JustSomeAnsi | 123 | 456789
       花花花花花花 | 123 | 456789
     追不到我别生气 | 123 | 456789
```

Now I know perfect alignment is not possible, but the example above would be tolerable to me. The question is how would you figure out how much to pad and with what [space char](https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html).

If context is relevant, this is being output into Unreal Engine console. I've already have replacement for original Roboto font - either [Sarasa Gothic](https://github.com/be5invis/Sarasa-Gothic) or [GNU Unifont](https://unifoundry.com/unifont/) or just any normal monospaced font like `Fira Code` + fallback for CJK (DroindSans right now, but it is not monospace)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: What for? This isn't the code snippet question, i.e. not like I have a specific piece of code that does not work, but rather genera/theoretical approach.

Comment: Check my last comment under this similar Q: [Need a single width unicode character to indicate a wide character has been shortened for lack of space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715754/)

Answer (score 0):

In Unicode, there are fullwidth versions of ASCII characters compatible with CJK in the U+FF00 code point block (See [Unicode code chart](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf)).

Here is your text using only fullwidth characters, including `IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE` U+3000:

```
　　　　　　　　　　　ＡＢＣ－花海　｜　１２３　｜　４５６７８９
　　　　　ＪｕｓｔＳｏｍｅＡｎｓｉ　｜　１２３　｜　４５６７８９
　　　　　　　　　　　花花花花花花　｜　１２３　｜　４５６７８９
　　　　　　　　　　追不到我别生气　｜　１２３　｜　４５６７８９
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4632373/235698) for a related Python-coded example that translates ASCII to the fullwidth forms.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Though I realized my input also has bunch of EUR symbols like russian alphabet, etc, some extra symbols and old-style emoji thrown into mix so this now becomes an impossible task.

Comment: You might want to look at [Unicode Standard Annex #11: East Asian Width](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/). If your content includes a mix of East Asian and European characters, that's a requirement that was supported in East Asian systems since before Unicode, and East Asian fonts would typically have Latin, Greek and Cyrillic characters that were exactly 1/2 the width of East Asian characters, as well as "fullwidth" variants of the European characters on other code points. See UAX #11 and the associated EastAsianWidth.txt data file that's part of the Unicode Standard.