# How is this gibberish created? I'm looking at the source but can't make sense of it

Tags: html, unicode, zalgo

Looking at this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/47589

How is the gibberish created?  I'm looking at the page source

```
<code>inal snuf</code>fing o<i>f the lie​<b>s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T 
A</b></i><b>LL I​S L</b>OST th<i>e pon̷y he come</i>s he c̶̮om<strike>es
he co</strike><b><strike>me</strike>s t<i>he</i> ich​</b>or permeat<i>es
al</i>l MY FAC<i>E MY FACE ᵒh god n<b>o NO NOO̼</b></i><b>O​O 
N</b>Θ stop t<i>he an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨ</i>e̠̅s<code> ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e</code> n<b>​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ
ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ T</b>O͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘<b>Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝</b>S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ</p>
```

I'm looking at the source HTML on the page (I can't paste it here; it gets rendered) but I expected to see unicode escape sequences.  I understand the basics of how Unicode works, but I can't figure out how to replicate this.

How do I replicate this gibberish with my own text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work

Comment: To add to that comment - Unicode escape sequences (= numeric character entities like `&x999999;` aren't necessary in HTML: the author is presumably simply using the correct characters directly.

Comment: Thank you, @remyabel.  I didn't know what to search for. Voting to close my own question.