# What the heck are these characters?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, zalgo

I recently read this post on stack overflow:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

The top reply contains text with text which appears to 'bleed':

ea͠ki̧n͘g fr̶ǫm ̡yo​͟ur eye͢s̸ ̛l̕ik͏e liq​uid pain, the song of re̸gular exp​ression parsing will exti​nguish the voices of mor​tal man from the sp​here I can see it can you see ̲͚̖͔̙î̩́t̲͎̩̱͔́̋̀ it is beautiful t​he final snuffing of the lie​s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

..

Lookig at these individually they look like single characters. How are they created? How can I find more information about them? For example, the "A" character:

A̡͊͠͝

WTF is that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Zalgo text work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work)

Comment: I confirm. It's a duplicate. Not that the question is not interresting, ***it is***, but the other question already covers the whole thing. :) Thanks to the other guys answering and commenting though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are combined Unicode characters.

```
http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode
```

and

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character
```