# How is this text able to run off the screen?

Tags: html, unicode, zalgo

Sorry, I know it's a little spam-ish, but here is the text in question.

Ỏ̷͖͈̞̩͎̻̫̫̜͉̠̫͕̭̭̫̫̹̗̹͈̼̠̖͍͚̥͈̮̼͕̠̤̯̻̥̬̗̼̳̤̳̬̪̹͚̞̼̠͕̼̠̦͚_Ỏ̷͖͈̞̩͎̻̫̫̜͉̠̫͕̭̭̫̫̹̗̹͈̼̠̖͍͚̥͈̮̼͕̠̤̯̻̥̬̗̼̳̤̳̬̪̹͚̞̼̠͕̼̠̦͚̫

How does this work? How is it able to run off the page like that?

Comment: thats freaky .. never saw something like this

Comment: I actually just saw something like this yesterday in a Google search results page...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character

Comment: Before it was closed yesterday, you had a response in the comments : It's unicode combining characters, Nothing about programming in here, and I'll let you read the wikipedia article about it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a trick that uses Combining Characters.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) is an article that explains it.

But if you want to know how this trick is performed based on Combining Characters;[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work) question on stackoverflow explains how it being done.
(Read all answers not only the first one).

Best wishes!

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see this is just some form of visual glitch or something visual as if you highlight the letters. The run off of these letters shall disappear up to where the div for where this is in ends.

This is just from me trying a few things

Comment: The fact that the characters seem to vanish if you select text is a bug in your web browser. A correctly behaving web browser would display those characters as is even if selected.