# What causes Zalgo text to do this?

Tags: html, twitter, unicode, zalgo

Before jumping the gun on anything, yes, I have looked at this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579844/5351192) already.

I've recently discovered the Twitter user '[@Glitchr_](http://twitter.com/Glitchr_)', and have been looking through some of his tweets and some of the "art" he makes. Something that caught my eye as I was scrolling down the page were these two things:

[image]

Now, you may think, *wow, backwards text. The title must be formatted like that.* 
But if you look into the HTML, here's what you find (Highlighted Text):

[image]

The second thing I found was this:

[image]

Some of the zalgo text also messed up the dates and somehow reversed it as shown.

So as stated in the title, ***What causes Zalgo text to do this?***

Answer (score 2):

The text contains `U+202E` (RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE), which indicates that the text should be rendered from right-to-left.

For example:

```
U+0041 U+0042 U+0043
ABC

U+202E U+0041 U+0042 U+0043
‮ABC
```

In this case, the character is in @glitchr_'s name: "Glitcher`<U+0020><U+202E>`".

Comment: Twitter does not allow for that many characters in a username.

Comment: @dylan The characters aren't in their username, they're in their profile name (and even if they were, it would still be under the length limit of 15 characters).

Comment: I meant profile name, and I don't believe twitter allows for more than twelve? EDIT: Just tried, can only hold twenty. How does he trick the webpage formatting though? Inserting that into my prof. name just outputs that rather than anything else.