# What is the unicode for the attached image?

Tags: unicode, symbols, zalgo

I am looking for the Unicode character for this image:

[image]
[image: High res image]

Does any one have any idea?  If yes, please provide the character.

This character is displayed in Mac pages when you type <kbd>Alt+space</kbd>.

Comment: See [What's alt+spacebar character and how to disable it?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34672/) and [How to disable the Option-Space key combination for non-breaking spaces?](http://superuser.com/questions/78245/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample picture is pretty unclear so it's hard to guess. However, it could be a kind of [Zalgo text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work) e.g. any bullet-like character modified by *Combining Circumflex Accent*.

For instance (using Windows Powershell; please note that my [`AltCodes.ps1` script](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602) is applied merely do display Unicode names ans UTF-8 values of used characters):

```
PS D:\PShell> $cf=[char]0x0302

PS D:\PShell> $cf+'.'+$cf+[char]0x2219+$cf+[char]0x2022+$cf+[char]0x2302
̂.̂∙̂•̂⌂

PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\tests\AltCodes.ps1 ' ̂.̂∙̂•̂⌂'

Ch Unicode    Alt?          IME     UTF-8   ?  

    U+0020      32         …32…      0x20      Space
 ̂   U+0302     770          …2…    0xCC82  Ì�  Combining Circumflex Accent
 .  U+002E      46         …46…      0x2E   .  Full Stop
 ̂   U+0302     770          …2…    0xCC82  Ì�  Combining Circumflex Accent
 ∙  U+2219    8729         …25…  0xE28899 â��  Bullet Operator
 ̂   U+0302     770          …2…    0xCC82  Ì�  Combining Circumflex Accent
 •  U+2022    8226         …34…  0xE280A2 â�¢  Bullet
 ̂   U+0302     770          …2…    0xCC82  Ì�  Combining Circumflex Accent
 ⌂  U+2302    8962          …2…  0xE28C82 â��  House

  ̂.̂∙̂•̂⌂

PS D:\PShell> ' ̂.̂∙̂•̂⌂'
 ̂.̂∙̂•̂⌂
```

**Viewport** from Powershell_ISE window:

[image: combining circumflex]