# How to achieve unusual text effect?

Tags: unicode

I was just reading a post and saw some odd text effects, however I cannot locate how it is achieved or what it is called:

P̢̢̲̭̘̣̪͉͞͞h̴̛̫͉͖̜͙̳͎̕͞͠'̶̀͢҉̯̞̹͈ṉ̶̘̠̯̬̭̖̳͘͞ģ̵̛͠҉̰̝͇̩͍̗͍̘̫͈̺̭̥͉l̨͍̘͔̰͔̖͍̹̠̭̱̰̖͙̦̦͎̕͟u̢̡҉̲̭̲̺̮̖͖͖i̴̢̹̳͉͎̥̪̜͎̼̣̦̖̻͈̖͉͚ͅ ̵͏͇̗̭ͅm̶̨͍̤̪̱͇̤̬̥̥͔̼͍̠̼͕g̷̷̰̩͙̪̫͉̺̯͘͟͠ļ̶̭͇̘̮̕͢ẃ̵̸̷҉͕̬̠̥̤͖̙̲͇̼̹'̺̩̖̟̣͈̖͙̤̫̰̗̯̀͡ń̷̴̶̰̮̺͔̼̺̹̘̟a̷̰̪͙͇̤͓̤̭͎̦͕̻f͏̨͙̰̘͔̟̜̠͈̯̻͕̖̳̝̝́͘ͅḩ̴̛͉͉̲͇̠͙̣̩͙̩͚̮̼̺ͅ ̧̛̟͓̤͇̯͍̫͖͎͈̫̳͓̞͘Ç͘͏͈̹̠̙͎̳̯͚͔̼͙̻͔͖̲̩̹̕ͅt͏̖̲̤̫̤̫̼̪̥̠͙͚͍̭́ͅḩ̡̲͈̫̯͚͉̱͍̳͝ù̧͙̭̙̻̲̙͚͔̲̬͚͢͝͡ḻ̴̵̨̹͉͙̟̯̞̠͔̦̝̩͜h̶̼̜̦͖͍͎͍̕ṷ̴̶̢͙̗̬͇̯̞̗̰̣̬̥̲̣̦ ̵̲͍̩̭̩̗͈͚͟͝R͏̛͘͟҉̫̝̞̪̣̪̻̤̼͖̪͎'̛̯͚͎̳͎̼͓̘͉͢l͟҉̵̘͈͙̣̹̜͍͎̬̺̹̪̜̀y͏͓̞̬͙̥̞̦͎͖̞͖͎̖̀e̶̵̡̺͉̯̭̣̗h͇̺͇̖̼̻̟͓͜͟͜͞ͅ ̴̷̡̨̪͍̙̳̞̭̙̫̯̘͚͇͚̼͙͟w̧̮̜̯̭̘͈̫̳̖̕͜͠g̢̨̗͖̬̠͎͓̱̞͓̭̯̺͕̭̯̦ͅa̴̠̘̬̩͍͜ͅh̵̷̨̜̻͔̖͈̤͈̩͔͈͇̩̞̲̜̩͍̺'̸̨͇̞̜͈͟n̨͟͞҉̤͚͎͇̣̺͚̻̖͖́ͅà̻͉̙̲̲̞͘͝ģ̙̗̙͓̜̣͔̥̫͟͡l̴̨̨̼͚̫̞̙̳͙͢͟ ̢̦͚̲͇̞̺̗̫͇f̸̸̫̠͖͙̜͉̲͖͓̭͇̦̭̩̲͡͠ḩ̸̲̤͍̖̻̣̝̼́̕͝ͅt̴͝҉҉̵͔̮̞̪á̢̕͢͏̗̯̗̙͙͉̪͓͙̣̰̣g͏̶̡͓̤͍͖̜̠̜ͅn̴̶̛̝̼͉̠̻͓

Don't worry though, unless thousands read it I think we are safe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work

Comment: @DaveCarruthers It isn't that complicated. Just **parse some HTML with regular expressions** and ẕ̡̫̫̞̋̅̀́̈́͟͠á̢̢̢̛̝̳͚̤͈̺͔̆̏̈̇̄̽͘ļ̶̛͙͉͕̼̍͐̈́̾̿͟͟͞ͅg̷̠̤̫̺͕͚̺̝̐̐͆̑̂̑̈̊̈̕ö̶͕̞̖̻̬̮͇́̐͆̽̽͛͢͜͝ t̬͈̫͎̰̼̽̄̍͌̀̏͋̚͡ͅͅͅė̢̡̛̺͖̳͙̞̊̾̆̈́̓̓͟͠x̶̡̪͔̻̫̗͖̺͕̰́̾̆͐͡t̨͉̦̗̱̥̝͑̑̇̍͘͟ w̶̢̧̮͇͖̫̠͎͉̓̈́̓͂̚͜į̖̺͎͇͙͖̎͂͐̒̊͛́͢͝͞l̶̛̼̲̹̝̓̈̓̊͘͜l̷̢͉̯͍̼͎̦̹̠͂̇̔̅̊̋͡ s̷̳̬͇̥̮͛̃̐̚͟͞͡͝͝h̵̨̨̝̟͉̘̩̜̲͗̈́̌̐̈́̂́̚͢o̧͖̹̩̠̟̗͍̾͒͑͞͠w̢̹͍̳͉͈͂͌̔͒͊͘ u̴̺̘͓͇̘̥̾̓͐́̔̅̏̕͝ṗ̶̼̦͚̙̜͙̘̗̥̑͗̀̒̋̓̔.̵̢̡̼̝̐̊̉̅̾͜.

Comment: P̘̥͉͙̬̣o̵̙s̶̯͚̰̼̬̺s̮̦͓̠̯͖̗ḭ̟̻̗̝b͙͘l̺̞̲e̞̥̱̙̦̗ ̢̺͇͉͉͕͎̣d̠͍̫͎͉ͅu̙̣̩̙̘̬̠p̦̲̣ͅl͇̞͈̲̩̙i͟c̷̣a̦̪t͖̭͠e͖͓̝̺̠̮̯ ҉͍͓o͉̖͍̮f̺̗̖͓͇̮ [Hò̻̣w̪ ̜̟͉̙͟ḑ͈͖o̝͖͝e͎͈͕̼̻̤͍s̗̰̰̠̖̯ ̪̦̟͚̳Z̷̠͓͉͔̹a̗̞̫̗͚̪͡lg̴̟̲͚̜̥̻o̳̣̰̖̗̫ ͕̠̦̲͉t͇͍̜e̮x͍͎̙͈͈͞ͅt̢̰̯̝̦̯ ̺͕wo̝͈̰͇̤r̲͉k?̭](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called **Zalgo text**.

You can [Google for](https://www.google.com/search?q=zalgo+text+generator) an online generator and use it:

> TH̘**Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝**S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

As a side note, [don't try to parse HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5958455).

Comment: thanks, will accept your answer as soon as it allows me.  Nice effect, never seen it before in 37 years of using a computer

Answer (score 1):

You can get a clue if you pick a sample and submit it to [Unicode character inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=C%CC%A7%CD%98%CD%8F%CC%95%CD%88%CC%B9%CC%A0%CC%99%CD%85%CD%8E%CC%B3%CC%AF%CD%9A%CD%94%CC%BC%CD%99%CC%BB%CD%94%CD%96%CC%B2%CC%A9%CC%B9t%CD%8F%CD%81%CC%96%CC%B2%CC%A4%CC%AB%CC%A4%CC%AB%CC%BC%CC%AA%CC%A5%CC%A0%CD%99%CD%9A%CD%8D%CD%85%CC%ADh%CC%A7%CD%9D%CC%A1%CC%B2%CD%88%CC%AB%CC%AF%CD%9A%CD%89%CC%B1%CD%8D%CC%B3u%CD%9D%CD%A1%CC%A7%CD%A2%CD%80%CD%99%CC%AD%CC%99%CC%BB%CC%B2%CC%99%CD%9A%CD%94%CC%B2%CC%AC%CD%9Al%CC%A8%CC%B4%CD%9C%CC%B5%CC%B1%CC%B9%CD%89%CD%99%CC%9F%CC%AF%CC%9E%CC%A0%CD%94%CC%A6%CC%9D%CC%A9h%CC%B6%CC%95%CC%BC%CC%9C%CC%A6%CD%96%CD%8D%CD%8E%CD%8Du%CC%B4%CC%A2%CC%B6%CC%AD%CD%99%CC%97%CC%AC%CD%87%CC%AF%CC%9E%CC%97%CC%B0%CC%A3%CC%AC%CC%A5%CC%B2%CC%A3%CC%A6%0D%0A):

```
C  U+0043  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C                Lu  Basic Latin
̧   U+0327  COMBINING CEDILLA                     Mn  Combining Diacritical Marks
͘   U+0358  COMBINING DOT ABOVE RIGHT             Mn  Combining Diacritical Marks
   U+034F  COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER             Mn  Combining Diacritical Marks
̕   U+0315  COMBINING COMMA ABOVE RIGHT           Mn  Combining Diacritical Marks
͈   U+0348  COMBINING DOUBLE VERTICAL LINE BELOW  Mn  Combining Diacritical Marks
[…]
```

… where `Lu` stands for [Unicode Character Category 'Letter, Uppercase'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/index.htm) and `Mn` stands for [Unicode Character Category 'Mark, Nonspacing'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/index.htm).

In short, they're just regular letters attached to all sort of combining diacritics, thanks to the magic of Unicode. It abuses the fact that `é` can also be written as `e` + `´` for entertainment purposes.