# First letter goes out of the paragraph box. How to fix that?

Tags: css

[image: Screenshot]
You can see in the screenshot that the first letter goes out of the box. I tried font-kerning property but it doesn't fix that. What should I do to start the letter "T" from the beginning.

PS: Only display block property is assigned to this paragraph, nothing else, and I think this font is kind of like that. Plus, I don't want to do this through paddings or margins. There must be a CSS property for this. Thanks

```
<div class="custom-font">
  <p>We are one big family implanted in the whole world.</p>
  <p>Winning, progress and teamwork are our priority.</p>
  <p>That’s why we design products exclusively for an elite</p>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/2jstmkp4/

Comment: I don't think you can control that, because it's a font thing but i'm not sure, however please include your code, so people can help you.

Comment: Wait, let me share the code snippet in a while.

Comment: this is for sure font specific .. like Zalgo is doing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work

Comment: Lets see if anyone else could help. Ill wait

Comment: Snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/2jstmkp4/

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to do it is through padding, but since you don't want to use it I don't know what other easy solution there is.

What is the reason you don't want to use padding/margin?

Comment: Because that is not a generic way to do this.

Comment: The problem is that your font goes out of its boundaries, it is wider than the reserved space on your screen. The part that falls of your block is outside the space for the char. So no css property will detect this.

Answer (score -1):

Try add this css code for paragraph:

```
p {
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: :( Then you have to use padding or margin