# How is this character encoded? ◡̈

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, diacritics

Someone texted me this character: `◡̈` They were using it as a smiley emoji, and depending where it's rendered, it looks either like two dots over a curve or two dots to the right of a curve.

When I saw it, I wondered if it came from some other language, so I opened wiki's [list of unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) and searched it. There are zero matches. Yet I know it must be there somehow since I'm able to use it.

Now here's the next thing: when I pasted the character into the searchbox in chrome to string-search the wiki page, it's a single character. But when I hit backspace, it only removes the dots, leaving the semi-circle which immediately matches `U+25E1`, "lower half circle."

So what is this? An umlaut over a lower half circle character? How does that work? Can you add accent marks on any arbitrary unicode character? If so, how? And how does that work with encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's copied from the title (◡̈) is encoded in UTF-8 as two characters with codes U+25E1 (0xE2 0x97 0xA1) and U+0308 (0xCC 0x88).

- [U+25E1](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U25A0.pdf) is LOWER HALF CIRCLE.
- [U+0308](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf) is COMBINING DIAERESIS.

The 'combining diaeresis' combines with another character.  It's not obvious why the characters are rendered differently in different places.  The Unicode standard says [Chapter 2: General Structure](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/ch02.pdf) p21:

> Combining characters (such as accents) are stored following the base character to which they apply, but are
>   positioned relative to that base character and thus do not follow a simple linear progression in the final rendered text.

You can find plenty of evidence for 'zalgo' on SO — they are mighty piles of combining characters:

@̮̘̮̜̤͓͓̓ͪ̓͆͗̑Ṷ̫̠̤̙̻͚̗ͭs̹͓̰̫͉̲̺̈̏̽̅̑ͩ̇̓̉e͖̝̦̦̿r͔̒̿̋̂̓n̹͖̥ͥͦͤ̍͊̏ä͇͖͚͖̃̎͊m̭͇̂͆͋̋͒e̫̠͇̰̱̦̹͗͋̓̿͒ ͔͖̫̬̗̪̪̳ͧ̄ͫB̜̥̣̬̮͈͒̄ͪ͊l̮͉̣̟̪̪̿̍ͫ͋͐̑a̜̦̪͗͗̈́ͣ͊ḫ̘̯͈̠̞͒ͯ ̣͕͚̗̠͖̫̆͌͒̓͛b̖̣͇̖̦̃̑ͬͭͥl͔͍͚͕̲̪̼͎ͧ̇̏ạ̖̪͚̯̊ͤͣͦͮ̌h̘͓͔̟͔͍̏ͣͦ̓̓ ̫̼̫ͮ͌̄ͤ̿̈͆b̙͍̼̜͍̹̬̬͎ͥ̓ͯ̂ḽ̜̟̲̾̅̆ͦ̃ͨa͇̰̝̺͊ͧͫ͛h̯̻͉̉̒̉̈́́ͥ̀.̖̩̭͇̭͔̹̈́̇͐ͬͦͦͨ̾̇.͍̪̣͂ͬ.̞͍̥̪̺̤̣̜͆ͫ̈́͑ͦ͂͑͑

See also:

- [How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work)

---

<sup>This shows the Unicode code points in the Zalgo text, 4 code points per line, working across the page and then down the page.  U+0040 is COMMERCIAL AT followed by 25 combining characters, for example, the first of which is U+032E COMBINING BREVE BELOW.</sup>

```
0x40 = U+0040            0xCC 0xAE = U+032E       0xCC 0x98 = U+0318       0xCC 0xAE = U+032E
0xCC 0x9C = U+031C       0xCC 0xA4 = U+0324       0xCD 0x93 = U+0353       0xCD 0x93 = U+0353
0xCC 0x93 = U+0313       0xCD 0xAA = U+036A       0xCC 0x93 = U+0313       0xCD 0x86 = U+0346
0xCD 0x97 = U+0357       0xCC 0x91 = U+0311       0xE1 0xB9 0xB6 = U+1E76  0xCC 0xAB = U+032B
0xCC 0xA0 = U+0320       0xCC 0xA4 = U+0324       0xCC 0x99 = U+0319       0xCC 0xBB = U+033B
0xCD 0x9A = U+035A       0xCC 0x97 = U+0317       0xCD 0xAD = U+036D       0x73 = U+0073
0xCC 0xB9 = U+0339       0xCD 0x93 = U+0353       0xCC 0xB0 = U+0330       0xCC 0xAB = U+032B
0xCD 0x89 = U+0349       0xCC 0xB2 = U+0332       0xCC 0xBA = U+033A       0xCC 0x88 = U+0308
0xCC 0x8F = U+030F       0xCC 0xBD = U+033D       0xCC 0x85 = U+0305       0xCC 0x91 = U+0311
0xCD 0xA9 = U+0369       0xCC 0x87 = U+0307       0xCC 0x93 = U+0313       0xCC 0x89 = U+0309
0x65 = U+0065            0xCD 0x96 = U+0356       0xCC 0x9D = U+031D       0xCC 0xA6 = U+0326
0xCC 0xA6 = U+0326       0xCC 0xBF = U+033F       0x72 = U+0072            0xCD 0x94 = U+0354
0xCC 0x92 = U+0312       0xCC 0xBF = U+033F       0xCC 0x8B = U+030B       0xCC 0x82 = U+0302
0xCC 0x93 = U+0313       0x6E = U+006E            0xCC 0xB9 = U+0339       0xCD 0x96 = U+0356
0xCC 0xA5 = U+0325       0xCD 0xA5 = U+0365       0xCD 0xA6 = U+0366       0xCD 0xA4 = U+0364
0xCC 0x8D = U+030D       0xCD 0x8A = U+034A       0xCC 0x8F = U+030F       0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4
0xCD 0x87 = U+0347       0xCD 0x96 = U+0356       0xCD 0x9A = U+035A       0xCD 0x96 = U+0356
0xCC 0x83 = U+0303       0xCC 0x8E = U+030E       0xCD 0x8A = U+034A       0x6D = U+006D
0xCC 0xAD = U+032D       0xCD 0x87 = U+0347       0xCC 0x82 = U+0302       0xCD 0x86 = U+0346
0xCD 0x8B = U+034B       0xCC 0x8B = U+030B       0xCD 0x92 = U+0352       0x65 = U+0065
0xCC 0xAB = U+032B       0xCC 0xA0 = U+0320       0xCD 0x87 = U+0347       0xCC 0xB0 = U+0330
0xCC 0xB1 = U+0331       0xCC 0xA6 = U+0326       0xCC 0xB9 = U+0339       0xCD 0x97 = U+0357
0xCD 0x8B = U+034B       0xCC 0x93 = U+0313       0xCC 0xBF = U+033F       0xCD 0x92 = U+0352
0x20 = U+0020            0xCD 0x94 = U+0354       0xCD 0x96 = U+0356       0xCC 0xAB = U+032B
0xCC 0xAC = U+032C       0xCC 0x97 = U+0317       0xCC 0xAA = U+032A       0xCC 0xAA = U+032A
0xCC 0xB3 = U+0333       0xCD 0xA7 = U+0367       0xCC 0x84 = U+0304       0xCD 0xAB = U+036B
0x42 = U+0042            0xCC 0x9C = U+031C       0xCC 0xA5 = U+0325       0xCC 0xA3 = U+0323
0xCC 0xAC = U+032C       0xCC 0xAE = U+032E       0xCD 0x88 = U+0348       0xCD 0x92 = U+0352
0xCC 0x84 = U+0304       0xCD 0xAA = U+036A       0xCD 0x8A = U+034A       0x6C = U+006C
0xCC 0xAE = U+032E       0xCD 0x89 = U+0349       0xCC 0xA3 = U+0323       0xCC 0x9F = U+031F
0xCC 0xAA = U+032A       0xCC 0xAA = U+032A       0xCC 0xBF = U+033F       0xCC 0x8D = U+030D
0xCD 0xAB = U+036B       0xCD 0x8B = U+034B       0xCD 0x90 = U+0350       0xCC 0x91 = U+0311
0x61 = U+0061            0xCC 0x9C = U+031C       0xCC 0xA6 = U+0326       0xCC 0xAA = U+032A
0xCD 0x97 = U+0357       0xCD 0x97 = U+0357       0xCC 0x88 = U+0308       0xCC 0x81 = U+0301
0xCD 0xA3 = U+0363       0xCD 0x8A = U+034A       0xE1 0xB8 0xAB = U+1E2B  0xCC 0x98 = U+0318
0xCC 0xAF = U+032F       0xCD 0x88 = U+0348       0xCC 0xA0 = U+0320       0xCC 0x9E = U+031E
0xCD 0x92 = U+0352       0xCD 0xAF = U+036F       0x20 = U+0020            0xCC 0xA3 = U+0323
0xCD 0x95 = U+0355       0xCD 0x9A = U+035A       0xCC 0x97 = U+0317       0xCC 0xA0 = U+0320
0xCD 0x96 = U+0356       0xCC 0xAB = U+032B       0xCC 0x86 = U+0306       0xCD 0x8C = U+034C
0xCD 0x92 = U+0352       0xCC 0x93 = U+0313       0xCD 0x9B = U+035B       0x62 = U+0062
0xCC 0x96 = U+0316       0xCC 0xA3 = U+0323       0xCD 0x87 = U+0347       0xCC 0x96 = U+0316
0xCC 0xA6 = U+0326       0xCC 0x83 = U+0303       0xCC 0x91 = U+0311       0xCD 0xAC = U+036C
0xCD 0xAD = U+036D       0xCD 0xA5 = U+0365       0x6C = U+006C            0xCD 0x94 = U+0354
0xCD 0x8D = U+034D       0xCD 0x9A = U+035A       0xCD 0x95 = U+0355       0xCC 0xB2 = U+0332
0xCC 0xAA = U+032A       0xCC 0xBC = U+033C       0xCD 0x8E = U+034E       0xCD 0xA7 = U+0367
0xCC 0x87 = U+0307       0xCC 0x8F = U+030F       0xE1 0xBA 0xA1 = U+1EA1  0xCC 0x96 = U+0316
0xCC 0xAA = U+032A       0xCD 0x9A = U+035A       0xCC 0xAF = U+032F       0xCC 0x8A = U+030A
0xCD 0xA4 = U+0364       0xCD 0xA3 = U+0363       0xCD 0xA6 = U+0366       0xCD 0xAE = U+036E
0xCC 0x8C = U+030C       0x68 = U+0068            0xCC 0x98 = U+0318       0xCD 0x93 = U+0353
0xCD 0x94 = U+0354       0xCC 0x9F = U+031F       0xCD 0x94 = U+0354       0xCD 0x8D = U+034D
0xCC 0x8F = U+030F       0xCD 0xA3 = U+0363       0xCD 0xA6 = U+0366       0xCC 0x93 = U+0313
0xCC 0x93 = U+0313       0x20 = U+0020            0xCC 0xAB = U+032B       0xCC 0xBC = U+033C
0xCC 0xAB = U+032B       0xCD 0xAE = U+036E       0xCD 0x8C = U+034C       0xCC 0x84 = U+0304
0xCD 0xA4 = U+0364       0xCC 0xBF = U+033F       0xCC 0x88 = U+0308       0xCD 0x86 = U+0346
0x62 = U+0062            0xCC 0x99 = U+0319       0xCD 0x8D = U+034D       0xCC 0xBC = U+033C
0xCC 0x9C = U+031C       0xCD 0x8D = U+034D       0xCC 0xB9 = U+0339       0xCC 0xAC = U+032C
0xCC 0xAC = U+032C       0xCD 0x8E = U+034E       0xCD 0xA5 = U+0365       0xCC 0x93 = U+0313
0xCD 0xAF = U+036F       0xCC 0x82 = U+0302       0xE1 0xB8 0xBD = U+1E3D  0xCC 0x9C = U+031C
0xCC 0x9F = U+031F       0xCC 0xB2 = U+0332       0xCC 0xBE = U+033E       0xCC 0x85 = U+0305
0xCC 0x86 = U+0306       0xCD 0xA6 = U+0366       0xCC 0x83 = U+0303       0xCD 0xA8 = U+0368
0x61 = U+0061            0xCD 0x87 = U+0347       0xCC 0xB0 = U+0330       0xCC 0x9D = U+031D
0xCC 0xBA = U+033A       0xCD 0x8A = U+034A       0xCD 0xA7 = U+0367       0xCD 0xAB = U+036B
0xCD 0x9B = U+035B       0x68 = U+0068            0xCC 0xAF = U+032F       0xCC 0xBB = U+033B
0xCD 0x89 = U+0349       0xCC 0x89 = U+0309       0xCC 0x92 = U+0312       0xCC 0x89 = U+0309
0xCC 0x88 = U+0308       0xCC 0x81 = U+0301       0xCC 0x81 = U+0301       0xCD 0xA5 = U+0365
0xCC 0x80 = U+0300       0x2E = U+002E            0xCC 0x96 = U+0316       0xCC 0xA9 = U+0329
0xCC 0xAD = U+032D       0xCD 0x87 = U+0347       0xCC 0xAD = U+032D       0xCD 0x94 = U+0354
0xCC 0xB9 = U+0339       0xCC 0x88 = U+0308       0xCC 0x81 = U+0301       0xCC 0x87 = U+0307
0xCD 0x90 = U+0350       0xCD 0xAC = U+036C       0xCD 0xA6 = U+0366       0xCD 0xA6 = U+0366
0xCD 0xA8 = U+0368       0xCC 0xBE = U+033E       0xCC 0x87 = U+0307       0x2E = U+002E
0xCD 0x8D = U+034D       0xCC 0xAA = U+032A       0xCC 0xA3 = U+0323       0xCD 0x82 = U+0342
0xCD 0xAC = U+036C       0x2E = U+002E            0xCC 0x9E = U+031E       0xCD 0x8D = U+034D
0xCC 0xA5 = U+0325       0xCC 0xAA = U+032A       0xCC 0xBA = U+033A       0xCC 0xA4 = U+0324
0xCC 0xA3 = U+0323       0xCC 0x9C = U+031C       0xCD 0x86 = U+0346       0xCD 0xAB = U+036B
0xCC 0x88 = U+0308       0xCC 0x81 = U+0301       0xCD 0x91 = U+0351       0xCD 0xA6 = U+0366
0xCD 0x82 = U+0342       0xCD 0x91 = U+0351       0xCD 0x91 = U+0351       0x0A = U+000A
```