# How can I find all hex codes for a Unicode character?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, escaping, python-re

I have to find some special characters using a Python regular expression. For example, for the character 'à',
I found some hex codes to build a regex pattern:

```
r'\x61\x300|\xe0|\x61\x300'
```

But I am afraid that I may miss some other hex codes.
How can I find all possible hex codes for a character?

Comment: Obligatory link: *[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)*.

Comment: @InSync Thank you. I am not a programmer, I am just an accountant.

Comment: ...who has 4 years of experience using StackOverflow and writing programming answers.

Comment: Do you mean that `à` (U+00E0,  *Latin Small Letter A With Grave*) is the same (excepting [normalization](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)) as 
`a` (U+0061,  *Latin Small Letter A*) followed by  ` (U+0300,  *Combining Grave Accent*)

Comment: @InSync just my hobby

Comment: Note that `\x30` is `0` (U+0030,  *Digit Zero*). Use `\u0300` for ` (U+0300,  *Combining Grave Accent*)…

Comment: @JosefZ I use hex(ord()) to print the character code and it returns x300

Comment: Depends on your definition of "character". If you consider those to be the same because of their appearance, do you also consider U+0041, U+0391, and U+0410 to be the same as well?

Comment: @InSync, an obligatory link back in 2003, but what devs should be aware of regarding Unicode is much more substantial and complex than the material in the article.

Comment: @JosefZ  U+00E0 and U+0061 U+0300 are canonical equivalents.  U+0061 U+0340 are also canonically equivalent, although use of these particular characters is discouraged, but may be found in very old data.

Comment: @DinhQuangTuan, exactly two hex digits are required in `\xhh` [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#escape-sequences)…

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You want something like

```
import unicodedata as u
import re

result = re.findall(
    u.normalize("NFC", "à"),
    u.normalize("NFC", inputstring))
```

If your regex needs to contain more than just a static literal string, probably compose it out of normalized Unicode strings and other regex constructs (though in simple cases individual regex primitives like `^` and `.` and `*` should be robust under Unicode normalization).

```
example = re.match(
    r'^' + u.normalize("NFC", "à") + r'$',
    u.normalize("NFC", inputstring)
similarly = re.finditer(
    f"^{u.normalize("NFC", "à")}$",
    u.normalize("NFC", inputstring)
yolo = re.search(
    u.normalize("NFC", r"^à$"),
    u.normalize("NFC", inputstring))
```

You can use another normalization if you prefer; the crucial requirement is to use the same normalization for both inputs. But NFC is recommended for this type of scenario.

See also https://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html and [Normalizing Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode)

To really solve the stated problem, you have to understand how normalization works. If there are multiple combining diacritics, you have to generate all possible orderings of them, for example. See also [How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work)

Comment: I'd be inclinded to use `result = re.findall("à", u.normalize("NFC", inputstring))`, the developer should know what normalisation form they are using for the pattern, but may not know what normalisation forms are in the data they are using. So easier to create a pattern then normalise the string to the normalisation form they used in the pattern.

Comment: @Andj That's a stretch IMHO. It's quite easy to open the file in an editor which gives you limited control over how exactly it is saved, especially on Windows.

Comment: Not too much of a stretch, reality is most applications and most input systems don't have options to generate NFD, actually using NFD can be difficult. Traditionally the most problematic has been Vietnamese windows didn't use NFC nor NFD for it. And it's only recent years that more LVT based fonts have become available for Korean making NFD practical.

Comment: Still, what ends up in the file is not necessarily strictly under the programmer's control, and even if it is, you have to be aware that you need to preserve that property when editing. Using \unnnn escapes would help, but doesn't guard against a naïve programmer making changes which are significant for the logic. I certainly would not trust most of my colleagues to understand this even if I left a comment.

Comment: I find few programmers know the first thing about Unicode, and even less likely to know which parts of Python follow Unicode, which parts diverge from Unicode, and which parts don't use Unicode. And by Unicode i am not just talking about characters and encodings. But seriously working with NFD is hard, lost of libraries and software assume NFC, and changes can occur in teh pipeline.

Comment: And with source code I am quite strict about the normalisation forms used by source files, and attempt to keep regex patterns compatible with that normalisation form.

Comment: If it's only you and you know what you are doing then of course, your approach is acceptable. I try to write answers on Stack Overflow which transfer easily and robustly to scenarios where the copy/paste victim might not even have read the full answer, let alone is cognizant of these nuances.

Answer (score 2):

What the OP required is a list of canonically equivalent codepoint sequences. The easiest solution is to use PyICU, which can provide canonical equivalents, then covert to regex pattern. This is a variation of code we use in our projects. The core is the `get_ce_pattern` function, which:

1. normalises the character
2. creates an icu iterator of canonical equivalents
3. use list comprehension of the iterator to help build a regex pattern

The function can be modified to process a string, or exclude deprecated characters.

**é** has three canonical forms, while **ộ** has five.

If there is only one the combining mark (diacritic), or if more than one and they belong to the same combining class, all you need is the NFC and NFD equivalents of the character (assuming deprecated marks are excluded from consideration).

If there are more than one diacritic, and some belong to different combining classes, then canonically equivalent variations outside of NFC and NFD forms also need to be considered.

```py
import icu
import regex as re

def get_ce_pattern(char, caseless=False):
    char = icu.Normalizer2.getNFCInstance().normalize(char)
    ci =  icu.CanonicalIterator(char)
    if caseless:
        return rf'(?i){"|".join([c for c in ci])}'
    return rf'{"|".join([c for c in ci])}'

line = "La sottise, l'erreur, le péché, la le\u0301sine,"
result = re.findall(get_ce_pattern('é'), line)
print(f"Pattern: {get_ce_pattern('é')}")
# Pattern: é|é|é
print(f"Result: {result}")
# Result: ['é', 'é', 'é']

line2 = "Trải qua mo\u0302\u0323t cuộc bể dâu"
result2 = re.findall(get_ce_pattern('ộ'), line2)
print(f"Pattern2: {get_ce_pattern('ộ')}")
# Pattern2: ộ|ộ|ộ|ộ|ộ
print(f"Result2: {result2}")
# Result2: ['ộ', 'ộ']
```

**Edit:**

Often when working with text from older PDF files, I tend to find presentation forms in the text, in which case canonical equivalents are insufficient, and it is necessary to work with compatibility decomposition as well. Starting with `get_ce_pattern`:

```py
def get_pf_pattern(char, caseless=False):
    results = [char, ud.normalize("NFKC", char)]
    if ud.normalize("NFKD", char) != ud.normalize("NFKC", char):
        results.append(ud.normalize("NFKD", char))
    if caseless:
        return rf'(?i){"|".join([c for c in results])}'
    return rf'{"|".join([c for c in results])}'

def equivalents_to_pattern(char, caseless=False):
    pattern = r'^[\p{Block=Alphabetic_Presentation_Forms}\p{Block=Arabic_Presentation_Forms_A}\p{Block=Arabic_Presentation_Forms_B}]$'
    if regex.match(pattern, char):
        return get_pf_pattern(char, caseless=caseless)
    return get_ce_pattern(char, caseless=caseless)

equivalents_to_pattern('å')
# 'å|å'
equivalents_to_pattern('\uFE82')
# 'ﺂ|آ|آ'
equivalents_to_pattern('á')
# 'á|á|á'
equivalents_to_pattern('á', caseless=True)
# '(?i)á|á|á'
equivalents_to_pattern('\uFB00')
# 'ﬀ|ff'
```

N.B. I am using the `regex` module instead of `re` since it supports Perl and Posix notation for Unicode blocks.

Comment: Do you use "canonical" incorrectly here? These characters have non-canonical representations which none of the canonical forms will cover; but I guess from your example that you attempt to create an exhaustive listing of possible representations.

Comment: I use canonical correctly. The first part of answer was specifically about canonical equivalence, the second section of code was compatibility equivalence which I did an edit to include. Of the final set of examples 3 are conical equivalence sets, 2 are compatability equivalence sets.

Comment: I can't test your code easily because (incredibly) `icu` depends on `tkinter` which is unavailable on stock MacOS Python. Does it correctly match `"o\0323\u0302"` as a variant? (Perhaps your examples could use \unnnn notation in the output?)

Comment: PyICU doesn't require `tkinter`. If icu4c and pkg-config are available, PyICU builds faily easily on macOS.

Comment: the generated pattern escaped: `r"\u1ED9|\u1ECD\u0302|\u00F4\u0323|o\u0323\u0302|o\u0302\u0323"` So, yes `o\0323\u0302` is included in that pattern.

Comment: Although i have limited the compatability equivalents to presentation forms. I should extend the code to all letetrs with compatibility decompositions. Although there are edge cases where I might want to use NFKC_CF.

Comment: My bad, I installed the `icu` package, not PyICU.